# Is using Mirth Connect or any other interface engine overkill in this situation?

Tags: web-services, hl7, mirth

I've been assigned a small project and directed to use Mirth Connect as part of the solution.  We currently do not use Mirth but because we have an upcoming project that will require an interface engine, I was asked to use it for this project so I can gain experience with it.  However, I think it's a poor suggestion for this project; I also know my boss would not want me to implement something that adds unnecessary complexity just for the sake of learning.

With that said, I want to make sure I have valid reasons for suggesting that Mirth Connect should not be used for this project.  Neither of us know much about it, but I think he's been convinced it is the end all solution for all things interface/webservice related.  I appreciate any input I can get from those of you who have more experience with the product than I have.

This is a very simple project in that we have a client needing to make a handful of requests into our system from there's in order to retrieve and update data.  For example, they will make a request to get patient demographics, to add an admission for a patient, a request to get a list of possible care settings from our application, etc.  For this project we will not use HL7 but a set of predefined XML messages.

Both the client's application and our application reside on the client's network.

They do not want to build any services of their own, so the services we build need to handle all of the work.  The results returned in response to their calls to the services will be returned as XML.

There are no plans to integrate any other applications with theirs or ours in the foreseeable future.

It seems to me the best option would be for us to build a standalone web service that would take their request and send back an XML response.  I just don't see any reason to include Mirth Connect in the picture (other than for learning but that can be gained in other ways).

What are your thoughts?  Is it true that the interface engine is not a good choice if the client wants to receive data from our system without having a receiving mechanism on their end?  In other words, they want to make a web service call such as GetCareSettings and to get a response back with an XML representation of all the possible care settings in our system.  It seems to me they would need a web service on their end for Mirth to use as a destination to send the results.  All Mirth is going to send back is an ACK message, correct?  (Unless of course it wrote the data to another webservice on the client end, which they have said they do not want to do.)

Thanks for taking the time to read this.  I hope my lack of knowledge and understanding of Mirth Connect and the use of interface engines hasn't made this question difficult to answer.

Comment: This question is not about logic but choice, but in my opinion it is a good question.+1

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Your client appears to be either a Lab or a third party service vendor, who will take inputs from your application like patient demographic charts, appointments, provider details etc. Basically he wants to *query* your application.

`A) HL7:` It has the capacity to handle query request and response with demographics. I am assuming that you have done you might be knowing about QRY messages.

`B) XML/webservices/SOAP:`still provides a viable solution, a little more concrete and can be expanded to Handle custom request like GetCallSettings, or may be any other. The vendor is not just interested in fetching patient related data but also other inputs for which HL7 might not be enough.

If we talk about approach, then its a professional advice to use an interface engine. It is not limited to just using mirth connect, you can also use Iguana if you want. A good reason which comes instantly to my mind is that an engine gives you an advantage while troubleshooting, support and maintenance activity.

Your Webservice responses can be handled easily by HTTP sender connector type and through [`RESTful webservices`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/). 
The engine is also capable of handling large volumes of request and responses at the same time, which in case is not required right now, but I think will be the condition later on. Your source in the channel shall change to an Webservice Listener.

Another good approach is to do away with `XML` and use `JSON` for handling request and responses, a much more light weighted than XML, to save your overhead with the network. We are doing some similar work, but we are sending request to a webservice through `JSON`.

Overall, Mirth is there to make your life more easier.

Good Luck!